# How to apply box muller transform to a time series?

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, data-transformation

I have a time series where each point is independent and uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. I want to apply the [box-muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to obtain a normally distributed time series. However I am unsure if I need to do this in a rolling window method to each pair of consecutive data points or some other way.

If we take the definition of the box muller transform, $Z_0 = \sqrt{-2\log U_1}\cos(2\pi U_2)$ and $Z_1=\sqrt{-2\log U_1}\sin(2\pi U_2)$ where $U_1, U_2$ and independent and uniformly distributed $U[0, 1]$. Then $Z_0, Z_1$ are independent normally distributed.

Given our uniformly distributed time series $X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3,...,x_n\}$, I would have done something like $Z = \{z_0=\sqrt{-2\log x_0}\cos(2\pi x_1), z_1=\sqrt{-2\log x_1}\sin(2\pi x_2), ..., z_{n-1}=..\}$. $Z$ has one less elemnt than $X$ as each point $z_i$ uses the last two data points to avoid look-ahead bias. But I'm not sure if this is valid.

How do I apply the box-muller transform to a time series? Is it even possible / correct to do so?

Comment: how did you get this time series to start with?

Comment: It's an interesting idea -- but note that the bivariate distributions of $(z_i,z_{i+1})$ will not be Normal (not even close) even though its marginals are Normal.  Thus, if you had been hoping to apply techniques to analyze Gaussian processes to $Z,$ you might be disappointed.

Comment: @whuber thanks for pointing that out... would it be the same problem if I applied [inverse transform sampling](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35281-transforming-uniform-variables-to-normal-variables) to the time series?

Comment: It's impossible to tell.  One way to characterize that situation would be that the joint distribution of $(x_i,x_{i+1})$ is a Gaussian copula.  I'm a little at a loss here because you are suggesting procedures without having articulated a statistical problem or without providing much to characterize your data.